# Insert data to a spatial database in postgis

Tags: database, postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I have create a table which has 3 fields: id(integer), name(char) and surface(polygon). When i try to insert a new row in this table by executing:

> INSERT INTO public."Area"
> ("ID", "Name", "Surface")
> VALUES(0, 'myArea', POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0)));

I get this error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "0"
> Position: 84

I searched in the documentation of postgis etc but i didnt find out how to define this field (same for points and linestring).

I also tried something like this:

> INSERT INTO public."Area"
> ("ID", "Name", "Surface")
> VALUES(1, 'myArea', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((8 4, 10.5 4, 10.5 1.5, 8 1.5, 8 4))'));

but the result was :

> SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: column "Surface" is of type polygon but expression is of type geometry
> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
> Position: 76

Could you please help me to find out which is my mistake?

Thank you a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Try [ST_PolygonFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PolygonFromText.html)
instead of ST_GeomFromText.

Or declare the column as generic GEOMETRY, rather than POLYGON type.

Comment: That will not work within an insert. You would still have to cast by hand by adding `::polygon`, and if you are to do this you might just as well stick to `st_geomFromText(..)::polygon` or more simply to use the text representation of PG native `polygon` type.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells the column is of type `polygon`, which is a [native postgres type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html). What one can do with this type is very limited and if you are working with spatial data, using Postgis and its `geometry` type is indicated.

To create a column containing geometries of the type polygon, with the projection `4326`, you would do

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (my_poly geometry(polygon,4326));
```

You can then load data using `ST_GeomFromText`.

Since your column is of `geometry` type, there is an automatic cast from `text` to `geometry`, or you can force it. Unlike in your 1st query, note that the polygon definition must be enclosed between quotes.

```sql
insert into test values ('polygon((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))'::geometry)
```

At last, it is technically possible to create a Postgis `geometry` and to cast it to Postgres native `polygon` type (`SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))')::polygon;`), but doing so brings very little benefit since you still won't have access to most of Postgis functions (compute distances, reproject, compute intersections etc)